# SQL - GROUP BY CASE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sort by state, then farms in that state where parent=id. How can I use ORDER BY CASE to accomplish this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, name, type,parent
FROM farm_components 
WHERE type='global' OR type='continent' OR type='country' OR type='region' OR type='farm'
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN type = 'global' THEN 1
WHEN type = 'continent' THEN 2
WHEN type = 'country' THEN 3
WHEN type = 'region' THEN 4
ELSE 5 END;
```

This is the current result:

[image]

This is the result I need:

```
Global
North America
United States
Colorado
Boulder
Denver
Fort Collins
Florida
Gainesville
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use ORDER BY CASE ?

I tried to achieve this whith WITH RECURSIVE :

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, name, parent, 1 lvl from farm_components
    union all
    select c.id, c.name, f.parent, lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join farm_components f on f.id = c.parent
)
select id, name, concat(group_concat(parent order by lvl desc), ',',id) grp
from cte
group by id, name
order by grp asc
```

You can check the result here : https://dbfiddle.uk/fU-MRrhq